# LINQ, "Value cannot be null", yet query evaluates

Tags: linq

I have the following linq query:

```
    var test = vendorContact.vendorContactItem
                     .Where(x => x.ItemNumber == vendorContactItem.Item_Number)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

It fails on this piece of code, "Value cannot be null, parameter name: source" ... yet it also displays, in the local variables window, "test" as a variable with all its properties populated.

`vendorContact.VendorContactItem` *is* null. Presumably this would be the first element to be added to the list. So how is "test" evaluating correctly while simultaneously throwing up that error?

I'm new to Linq, so excuse me if this is an obvious question.

Comment: `vendorContact.VendorContactItem` cannot be both null and an empty list. Which is it?

Comment: "null" and "a list with no elements" are two different things.

Comment: The LINQ extension methods (all extension methods) are invoked as: `fn(obj, p1, p2, ...)`. That is, they are not invoked upon a receiver (they are static methods) and thus can react to null (e.g. when `obj == null`) how they choose to. Usually throwing an ArgumentNullException is appropriate. Not sure if this answers/explains your question though.

Comment: Good catch guys, you are correct it is not an empty list, it is actually null, I have edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in a loop `test` in the locals window contains the last value of `test`, from the last iteration of the loop.

**Edit:** This has really nothing to do with LINQ, but how the debugger works.

Comment: Ah ha! Well, I did say the answer might be obvious. Thanks a bunch!